# Website not centered in IE due to jquery onebyone slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, slider

I have put a jquery slider onto the index page of my website. In IE this slider is making my website display on the left hand side of the screen rather than in the center just for this page.

Not sure why - I have a test page live if anyone has any ideas it would be great as I have been trying to fix for more than a week.

http://www.coverforce.com.au/index-bu.php

Also, FYI the styling of the slider has not been done yet so please don't judge my ugly testing slides lol.

Thanks for your time  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.onebyone.min.js"></script>   
<script src="/js/jquery.touchwipe.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
     $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#banner').oneByOne({
            className: 'oneByOne1',              
            easeType: 'random',
            slideShow: true
        });  


     });


    </script>
```

Into the `<head>` or just before the end `</body>` tag. Right now IE is in quirks mode because the DOCTYPE isn't the first thing in the document.

In quirks mode, `auto` horizontal margins don't work the same as standards, this is probably the issue.